# Can i programmatically rename a file on removable sd card

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-sdcard, file-rename

I tried below codes for renaming file.It works fine for internal storage but is not working for removable sd card file.I need to rename file on removable sd card to remove spaces and special characters from filename as I am using fmpeg command to cut videos.

```
File from = new File(originalpath);
String rename=originalpath.replace(" ", "").replace("-","").replace(",","").trim();
File to = new File(rename);
Boolean result= from.renameTo(to);
```

OR

```
File from = new File(originalpath);
File to=new File((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()),"gvideo.mp4");
Boolean result2= from.renameTo(to);
```

Both of them gives result false

Adding details about command-

```
execFFmpegBinary("-i " + from.getAbsolutePath() + " -ss " + startMs / 1000 + " -to " + endMs / 1000 + " -strict -2 -async 1 " + dest.getAbsolutePath());
private void execFFmpegBinary(final String command) {
        try {
            ffmpeg.execute(command, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(String s) {
                    Log.e("Previewragment", "FAILED with output : " + s);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String s) {
                    Log.e("Previewragment", "SUCCESS with output : " + s);
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgress(String s) {
                    Log.e("Previewragment", "Started command : ffmpeg " + command);
                    Log.e("Previewragment", "progress : " + s);
                }

                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    Log.e("Previewragment", "Started command : ffmpeg " + command);

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    Log.e("Previewragment", "Finished command : ffmpeg " + command);



                }
            });
        } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
            // do nothing for now
        }
    }
```

Failure message-

```
FAILED with output : WARNING: linker: /data/data/xyz/files/ffmpeg has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
    ffmpeg version n2.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
    built on Oct  7 2014 15:11:41 with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
    configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/i686-linux-android- --arch=x86 --cpu=i686 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/build/x86 --extra-cflags='-I/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all -march=i686' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
    libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
    libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
    libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
    libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
    libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
    libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
    libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
    libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
    "/storage/emulated/0/Movies/m_ASUS_Display_Demo.mp4": No such file or directory
```

Added complete method-

```
private void executeTrimCommand(int startMs, int endMs) {

        File moviesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES
        );

        String filePrefix = "guggu";
        String fileExtn = ".mp4";
        String fileName = filePrefix + fileExtn;

       File from = new File(path);

        try {


            dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + "_1" + fileExtn);

            if (dest.exists()) {
                dest.delete();
            }



            String command = String.format("-i \"%s\" -ss %d -to %d -strict -2 -async 1 \"%s\" ",path,startMs / 1000 , endMs / 1000, dest.getAbsolutePath());
            execFFmpegBinary(command);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Previewragment", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: [External storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare check out my first code befor "0R"..in that i am passing `originalpath` which is the path of video of removable sd card..so what should i replace `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` with??

Comment: did you add write external storage permission?

Comment: @HarishSridharan yeah..i added that

Comment: "which is the path of video of removable sd card" -- on Android 4.4+, you do not have access to removable storage, other than what you can get from `getExternalFilesDirs()` and kin. Beyond that, in your first sample, you are replacing characters in the entire path, which might affect directories in addition to the file, and you cannot rename directories and a file in one shot. In your second example, you cannot rename across filesystems, and if `originalpath` really is from removable storage, that will be a different filesystem than is external storage.

Comment: @CommonsWare okay..so is there any way i can rename file of removable sd card in android lollipop?And secondally as replacing characters in entire path can effect directories then how should i proceed in replacing characters and spaces in filename if i have the complete path of the video?In my project i am fetching paths of all videos from internal and external storage..glad if u can help me wid answer

Comment: @CommonsWare I am using this ffmpeg command to cut videos..and this command fails if there are spaces in the filename of source video? `"-i " + source.getAbsolutePath() + " -ss " + startMs / 1000 + " -to " + endMs / 1000 + " -strict -2 -async 1 " + dest.getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: "so is there any way i can rename file of removable sd card in android lollipop?" -- only if it is located somewhere that you can read and write (e.g., `getExternalFilesDirs()`), and then only if you *only* rename the *file*, not the path.

Comment: Command fails if you have spaces since because spaces in file name can make the command to have more arguments. Did you try to quote your command?

Like this:
"-i " + source.getAbsolutePath() + " -ss " + startMs / 1000 + " -to " + endMs / 1000 + " -strict -2 -async 1 \"" + dest.getAbsolutePath() +"\" "

Comment: @HarishSridharan u mean i should add ` \ ` after `async 1` and  `+"\" "` in the  end?..Here is my complete command..How can i quote it?  `"-i " + to.getAbsolutePath() + " -ss " + startMs / 1000 + " -to " + endMs / 1000 + " -strict -2 -async 1 " + dest.getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: @CommonsWare How can i use getExternalFilesDirs() for renaming file?

Comment: @HarishSridharan Sorry,I don't understand what do you mean by quoting command?

Comment: **\"** after async 1  and **+"\" "** in the end. Use string formatter instead. I'll add the string formatter as an answer.

Comment: Let me try to explain about quoting at the simplest means. Lets say you want to copy the file in linux using `cp` command. It takes two arguments one for the source and one for the destination. The syntax will be `cp folder1/file1 folder2/file2`. But if the folder2 in the above syntax is having a space in it, you have to quote it otherwise would be considered as cp with 3 arg command [remember we use spaces to separate arguments]. So the command will be `cp "folder1/file1" "folderwithspace2/file2"`. Did you get this?

Answer (score 1):

For the comment in the question, Usage of String formatter:

```
String command = String.format("-i \"%s\" -ss %d -to %d -strict -2 -async 1 \"%s\" ",to.getAbsolutePath(),startMs / 1000 , endMs / 1000, dest.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: for destination path i see `\"%s\ ` and for source path i just see `%s`.. why is that difference?And space issue was in source path..

Comment: its not working..i am again posting actual command i am using `"-i " + from.getAbsolutePath() + " -ss " + startMs / 1000 + " -to " + endMs / 1000 + " -strict -2 -async 1 " + dest.getAbsolutePath()`;

Comment: Edited the answer to quote source path as well. I thought the problem was in dest path alone.

Comment: Thanku for ur effort but its still not working.I have added in question details about command..please check out in question

Comment: Thanks. Also post what was the failure message you received in onFailure callback. Also note, not to leave catch block empty, put out `e.printStackTrace();` always.

Comment: I added failure message..its failing for both internal and external storage video

Comment: if i add string formatter it even fails for videos which doesn't have space.i am again writing the original command which i was using `execFFmpegBinary("-i " + path + " -ss " + startMs / 1000 + " -to " + endMs / 1000 + " -strict -2 -async 1 " + dest.getAbsolutePath());` ..after ur answer i changed it too- `String command = String.format("-i \"%s\" -ss %d -to %d -strict -2 -async 1 \"%s\" ",path,startMs / 1000 , endMs / 1000, dest.getAbsolutePath());
            execFFmpegBinary(command); ` ..please let me know where am i wrong..original command works fine for videos which doesn't have space..

Comment: check out this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779303/handling-spaces-in-filenames-of-ffmpeg-command-when-i-dont-know-the-exact-path

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in the context of a shell, the path returned from `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` will throw an error that the file or directory does not exist.

You need to change all file paths which you send to be run in a shell. Here is a static factory method you can use to get the correct File:

```
/**
 * The external storage path is not readable by shell or root. This replaces {@link
 * Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()} with the environmental variable
 * "EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
 *
 * @param file
 *         The file to check.
 * @return The original file (if it does not start with {@link
 * Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()})
 * or a file with the correct path.
 */
@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
public static File fileForShell(File file) {
    String externalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    if (!file.getAbsolutePath().startsWith(externalStorage)) {
        return file;
    }

    String legacyStorage = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
    String path;

    if (legacyStorage != null) {
        path = file.getAbsolutePath().replaceFirst(externalStorage, legacyStorage);
    } else {
        path = file.getAbsolutePath().replaceFirst(externalStorage, "/sdcard");
    }

    return new File(path);
}
```

When you create the command just use the above method to get the correct file path.

```
File from = ...
File fileToUseInCommand = fileForShell(from);
...
```

Comment: i have just updated question with complete method..please check it and let me know what should i add and where?thanks..

Comment: I updated my answer. Hopefully that makes it clear on what you need to do before sending a command to your shell.

Comment: so should i try this `from=fileForShell(from);
            dest=fileForShell(dest);
            String command = String.format("-i \"%s\" -ss %d -to %d -strict -2 -async 1 \"%s\" ",from.getAbsolutePath(),startMs / 1000 , endMs / 1000, dest.getAbsolutePath());`

Comment: not working..  "/storage/emulated/legacy/Movies/m_ASUS_Display_Demo.mp4": No such file or directory

Comment: Hmm... Have you tried running the command from adb shell? Are you sure the file exists? Your question is kind of vague.

Comment: check out this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779303/handling-spaces-in-filenames-of-ffmpeg-command-when-i-dont-know-the-exact-path